# Defining Precompactness in terms of Cauchy sequences

Tags: real-analysis

The definition of precompactness is:

> If $A$ is a subset of a metric space $X$, then $A$ is called precompact if every sequence in $A$ has a convergence subsequence in $X$.

But, is the following true?

> $A$ is precompact if and only if every sequence in $A$ has a Cauchy susbsequence

Comment: Since a counterexample in the general case has been provided, I will simply add that if $X$ is a complete metric space, then your statement does hold: every Cauchy sequence converges, and you immediately recover the original definition.

Answer (score 1):

No, consider $X=A=(0,1)$: its adherence in $R$ is the compact interval $[0,1]$, so every sequence $(x_n\in [0,1])$ has a convergent subsequence in $[0,1]$, and this subsequence is Cauchy in $A=(0,1)$ but does not necessarily converge in $X=(0,1)$. Specifically, if the subsequence converges to $0$ or to $1$ in $[0,1]$, it does not converge in $X$.

Comment: Taking $X=(0,1)$ and $A=X$? If you take $X$ to be $[0,1]$ then the statements are equivalent since $[0,1]$ is compact and complete.

Comment: I take $X=A=(0,1)$

Comment: @SamM: Tsemo is not taking $X$ to be $[0,1]$. He’s arguing that if $\sigma$ is a sequence in $X=(0,1)$, then $\sigma$ can also be viewed as a sequence in $[0,1]$, where of course it has a convergent subsequence $\sigma'$ in $[0,1]$. This forces $\sigma'$ to be Cauchy in $[0,1]$ and hence in $X$, since the metric on $X$ agrees with the one on $[0,1]$, However, if $\sigma'$ converges in $[0,1]$ to either $0$ or $1$, it is not convergent in $X$ despite being Cauchy.